# I want one of my monitors act like the laptop monitor

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have connected two monitors to my laptop:
[image]
**Monitor 1:** Laptop monitor.
**Monitor 2:** External monitor connected through VGA port.
**Monitor 3:** External monitor connected through HDMI port.

I want to completely disable my laptop monitor, and let Monitor 2 act like the built-in display. So, when I switch between "Second screen only" and "Extend" options, I get either Monitors 2 and 3 both, or only Monitor 3.

I am able to disable my laptop monitor by selecting "disconnect this display"

[image]

However, now, I cannot use "Extend" and "Second screen only" options properly. When I select "Second screen only," the display is extended to Monitors 2 and 3.
When I select "PC screen only," it enables Monitor 1, and disables Monitors 2 and 3.

[image]

What I want is, "Extend" should show extended display to Monitors 2 and 3, and "Second screen only" should show only Monitor 3.

This way, I will not go to settings and disable Monitor 2 whenever I want to use only Monitor 3.

To sum up, I would like to have only two displays.
**Second screen only:** Only Monitor 2.
**Extended display:** Monitors 2 and 3.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I have a three screen setup including my Laptop, however I do not have the option to "Disconnect this Display" for my laptop screen since it is not my main display.  I can however close the lid which turns the screen off for it (after adjusting the settings for what closing the lid does).  From there, I am able to switch between extended and Second Screen only without issues.  I suppose what I am saying here is perhaps close the lid of the laptop when you don't need to use the display to achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: @TimG. I tried this, but then the cursor moves to the laptop screen as it is not disabled. And I do not have a "turn screen off" option when the lid is closed.